# Difference between Geographic and Projected coordinate systems?

Tags: coordinate-system, differences

What is the difference between a geographic coordinate system and a projected coordinate system?

Comment: This looks like two questions so to fit the Q&A format of GIS-SE would you be able to focus this Question on the one you would like answered first, please?

Comment: @PolyGeo kindly give me the answer to the first question I have posted.

Comment: This looks like you are trying to re-use a closed Question for a new one.  I recommend that this one is rolled back and remains closed (as a duplicate) and that a second Question be asked with considerably more detail about what exactly is being asked.

Comment: As someone who wants to know the answer to *this* question, the *other* question talks about different concepts which just confuses me.  As such, although I understand what *this* question is asking I do not understand what the *other* question is asking.  I believe this question should be 'unduplicated'

Comment: @ChrisSnow This was a messy Q&A because it started with two questions (see [Tour] for desirability of one question per question), then the first was answered and accepted by the asker, then the asker changed the question to be the other one.  If this Q&A does not answer what you need to know, which I think is the answer to the original second question, then I recommend researching/asking it as a new question.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because this question  the users should have know already before ask a question.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Geographic Coordinate Systems:

http://help.arcgis.com/en/arcgisdesktop/10.0/help/index.html#/What_are_geographic_coordinate_systems/003r00000006000000/

Projected Coordinate Systems:

http://help.arcgis.com/en/arcgisdesktop/10.0/help/index.html#/What_are_projected_coordinate_systems/003r0000000p000000/