# Converting distance to coords?

Tags: coordinate-system, coordinates, gis-principle

I want to convert a coords interval (especially latitude) to real distance.

I mean let's say we stay at the exact same longitude, but with 1 degree of difference in latitude.

How many kilometers/meters/whatever does this 1-dimensional bounding box amount to?

Is there some type to do the conversion?

Comment: Yes, the conversion is called projection. You need to know the lat/long datum and desired projection. Not for all coordinates the output is similar. [Check this question](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/182444/understanding-difference-between-coordinate-system-and-projection)

Comment: You can do this calculation for a given pair of points, but since the Earth is modeled with an *oblate spheroid*, the values will change slightly at different latitudes, and the difference is *huge* along parallels. Research the "two problems of geodesy" for more details.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I will atempt to answer your questions in three different ways:

1. A degree of latitude is approximately 111 km. It varies from 110.567 km at the equator to 111.699 km at the poles. Taken from [here](https://www.thoughtco.com/degree-of-latitude-and-longitude-distance-4070616).
2. You can calcutale it yourself online [here at NOAA](http://www.nhc.noaa.gov/gccalc.shtml).
3. This previous answers undertakes the background of the calculations you are asking for http://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/75528/understanding-terms-in-length-of-degree-formula/75535#75535